# Error al usar headers(.h) en archivos .cpp

Tags: c++, lista, clase, class, headers

Tengo 3 archivos, uno se llama `main.cpp` , `menu.h` , `lista_generica_simplemente_enlazada.h`. Mi código es bastante extenso, pero por los títulos de los archivos ya saben masomenos de que trata.

**lista_simplemente_enlazada**

```
#include <iostream>
```

**menu.h**

```
#include <iostream>
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lista_simplemente_enlazada.h"
#include "menu.h"
```

Cuando lo compilo así, funciona muy bien. Pero en el archivo `menu.h` me subraya las funciones instanciadas como si fueran erroneas, ya que las funciones creadas están en `lista_generica_simplemente_enlazada.h`, así que decidí agregarle a el archivo `menu.h` el archivo `lista_generica_simplemente_enlazada.h` y me dejó de subrayarlas de rojo. O sea así:

**lista_simplemente_enlazada**

```
#include <iostream>
```

**menu.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lista_simplemente_enlazada.h" //ACÁ ESTÁ
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lista_simplemente_enlazada.h" 
#include "menu.h"
```

Al compilar el archivo `main.cpp` me sale una serie de muchos errores de **definition** y **redefinition** de Clases.

**¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? o ¿Por qué pasa esto?**, **¿Debo dejar que algunas funciones se marquen con rojo?** (Estoy usando VSCODE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al utilizar la instuccion del preprocesador `#include`, recuerda que el compilador copia y pega lo que haya en el archivo. Por ejemplo:

**hola.h**

```
void saludar(void) {
  std::cout << "Hola\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include"hola.h"

int main() {
  saludar();
  return 0;
}
```

Al pasar por el preprocesador el resultado es este:

```
void saludar(void) {
  std::cout << "Hola\n";
}

int main() {
  saludar();
  return 0;
}
```

Literalemente copia y pega lo que haya en el archivo.

Entoces lo que sucede es que estas colocando el mismo codigo varias veces en lugares diferentes, por eso te sale que lo defines varias veces. A mi me pasa lo mismo con visual studio code, no te preocupes, le toma unos minutos darse cuenta de como van los archivos. Si le das unos momentos (que a mi parecer, son unos momentos muy largos, no se porque no se arregla ese error), los errores desaparecen.

Lo que puedes hacer en el fututo es usar las famosas guardias `#ifndef`

**hola.h mejorado**

```
#ifndef HOLA_HEADER
#define HOLA_HEADER
void saludar(void) {
  std::cout << "Hola\n";
}
#endif
```

Asi no importa cuantas veces lo incluyas, solo se va a colocar el codigo una vez. Puedes ver mas sobre estas en la [style guide de Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#The__define_Guard). Y aqui un [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RJTQmK0YPI) de `The Cherno` explicando de una buena manera (en mi opinion), como funcionan los header files.